# How to launch dired plus

Tags: emacs, dired

I've placed the [dired plus](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) file in `~/.emacs.d`, added `(require 'dired+)` to my `~/.emacs` file and restarted Emacs. How do I launch dired plus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dired+ adds functionality to dired, so you don't launch Dired+ as such - just run dired as you would normally (e.g. `M-x dired`) and the added functionality should be available.

If Dired+ isn't loading, make sure that `~/.emacs.d` is in your load-path - add this line to your init file if necessary:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
```

**Edit:** As event_jr says, you should avoid adding `.emacs.d` to your `load-path` - create a new directory in `~/.emacs.d`, install your Emacs Lisp files there, and add that directory to `load-path`. My answer was intended to fix your immediate problem, given where you'd installed the Dired+ file, not a recommendation to install packages in `~/.emacs.d`.

Comment: Thanks. I ran `M-x` `dired` and the "normal" dired appeared. Just tried it again and now dired plus is appears (the various columns are in different colours). [You may want to correct the `.` in `~/.emacs.d` path in your answer.]

Comment: @SabreWolfy `~/.emacs.d` does not go in your load-path.  This directory is meant to store configuration files, not lisp packages.  see: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2012-03/msg00057.html

Comment: ^ So I should make a separate folder for Lisp packages? Under `~/.emacs.d`?

Comment: @SabreWolfy - http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsDotD - "The user directory itself is not part of load-path, and since it contains other things than libraries, you should leave it at that. Instead, you should install packages in a dedicated sub-directory (e.g., ~/.emacs.d/elisp) and add that to the load-path instead."

Comment: @SabreWolfy - you can put your Lisp packages in a directory under ~/.emacs.d, or another directory outside of it (which is what I do), but either way, you will have to explicitly add the directory to your load-path variable.

Comment: But, how can I confirm that the dired+ is correctly loaded? I use it in windows,  but seems no difference after I installed dired+